# Joomla 3.0 missing menu parameters

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla3.0

Has been some time till I last worked in Joomla (that was verion 1.5.x)

In Joomla 3.0 the Menu parameters seems to be missing. Adding the parameter helped identifying what menu item has been clicked. The problem I am having now is that if I use the same component for two different menu items in the main menu - it will basically do the same.

BEFORE (Example):

Menu Item (1) - Landscape pictures (Menu parameter is set to 1)

-> Calls com_picturegallery
-> See's that parameter is ONE and select statement of component filters for all landscape pictures.

Menu Item (2) - Urban pictures (Menu parameter is set to 2)

-> Calls com_picturegallery
-> See's that parameter is TWO and select statement of component filters for all urban pictures.

In Joomla 3.0 i cannot find an option to set these parameters in the menu settings for main menu.

Does anyone know how else to tell Joomla that depending on menu I click the component has to do a specific task.

Thanks!

Comment: I should mention that I the "leading" parameter in the menu settings in Joomla 1.5.x was meant to define how many articles should be displayed in full I think ... not sure. I simply used it to tell my component what menu has been clicked and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works - I suppose it has been also best practice in Joomla 1.5.x

```
$menu = JSite::getMenu();
$alias = $menu->getActive()->alias;
```